# Drop down list inside a pop up window (comes up when button is pressed)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently I'm trying to create a button which creates a popup box which in turn has a drop down list, like in [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp). However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to put the drop down list inside the pop up window. Can anyone help?

I currently have a pop up window with a form, but I want to change this form into a drop down list. refer this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tchchan/L8PVz/3/)

```
<p>Do you have an agreement or a conflict?</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "");

}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. In order to help you, we need to see the code you've tried (even if it's broken or only in psuedocode), and you need to tell us what it is that you expect it to look like when it'd done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a possible demo solution.

```js
$('#dialog').hide();
$('#target').click(function() {
  $('#dialog').show();
  $('#dialog').dialog();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</div>

<input type="button" id="target" value="click" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using **prompt** which is default for all `browser` having **input**.

If you want popup with select dropdown you have to create **custom popup**.

Here is **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Uj834/)** using [BootStrap model](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

Comment: Thank you! this is what I was looking for. Do I need to include anything? It isn't working when I run it on a html file off my browser.

Comment: you have to add libraries of bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

when dropbox change event fires catch selected item and do your work or just use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5UT5q/421/)

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog"> <p id="dropdownselectitem"> </p> </div>  <select id="dd">  <option value="Select Cars...">Select Cars...</option>   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>   <option value="saab">Saab</option>   <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>   <option value="audi">Audi</option> </select>

$( "#dialog" ).hide();
$( "#dd" ).change(function() {
$('#dropdownselectitem').html($('#dd').val());
      $( "#dialog" ).show();
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});
```