# Show popup with selections

Tags: javascript, jquery

4. I am new to JavaScript/jQuery.

   - When the page initially loads, show a popup for the user to select the country.  It should look like this:
     [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfU9I.png)
   - Upon selection of “United States”, it should look like this:
     [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSHyh.png)
   - There are only two selections: “United States” and “Canada”.

     - Upon selection of “United States”, show another drop-down list containing the list of states.
     - Upon selection of “Canada” or a state, close the popup.

Comment: This isn't really how SO works. I'd suggest searching the web to get started, then coming back with a specific question regarding code-in-progress.

Comment: @user8448056 what does the `4.` stand for in the question, homework question no :p

Comment: Is this question 4 in your test?

Comment: This is my fourth question that i have posted on stack overflow..

Comment: But you have only asked one question here.lol

Comment: @user8448056 Did you delete the other three?

Answer (score 0):

Just go through this code.
You can open model window on document.ready method in jQuery this method triggers when the html page is ready.
Then you can show the state dropdown if the country is selected in the change event of country dropdown. You can also append the options for the selected country inside change event of dropdown.

```js
$("#cntry").change(function(){
 if(this.value!="Select Country")
   {
     $('#state').find('option').remove().end().append('<option value="Select State">Select State</option>');
    
     if(this.value=="United States")
     {
      $("#state").append("<option vaue='USA State 1'>USA State 1</option>");
      $("#state").append("<option vaue='USA State 2'>USA State 2</option>");
     }
     else if(this.value=="Canada"){
     $("#state").append("<option vaue='Canada State 1'>Canada State 1</option>");
      $("#state").append("<option vaue='Canada State 2'>Canada State 2</option>");
    }
    
    $("#divstate").show();
   }
   else{
   $("#divstate").hide();
   }
});
 

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnPopup").click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
<div class="container">
  <h2>Example Modal on Page Load</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button style="display:none" id="btnPopup" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">To proceed: Select Country</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
         <div> 
           <select class="form-control" ID="cntry">
     <option class="form-control" value="United States">United States</option>
      <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
             <option selected value="Select Country">Select Country</option>
       </select>
         </div>
         <div id="divstate" style="display:none">  
         <select class="form-control" ID="state">
        <option value="Select State">Select State</option>
       </select>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Is this is your expected output that you need?

Answer (score -1):

You should definitely do some research yourself, but this will be something that works:

```
var country = window.prompt("Please enter 'United States' or 'Canada'", "Enter your country");
```

But it is not a dropdown. In html you can, however, use the `<select>` option. So if you really want a dropdown, you should create a pop-up with html yourself. Take a look at this question: [Drop down list inside a pop up window (comes up when button is pressed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949285/drop-down-list-inside-a-pop-up-window-comes-up-when-button-is-pressed)